# Flutter How to use page.dart as the Navbar of the whole application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm really new to flutter, I don't know if this is crazy or not, but hopefully, I can make it.

I have created a `StatefulWidget` named `LayOut` and it is arranged like this:

I will share all about it at the link here: [here](https://paste.mod.gg/pyjfmrqhixzh/0)

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(), **//Irrelevant code**
          SafeArea(child: Container()), **//Irrelevant code**
          TweenAnimationBuilder(
              tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: value),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              curve: Curves.easeInExpo,
              builder: (_, double val, __) {
                return (Transform(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    transform: Matrix4.identity()
                      ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                      ..setEntry(0, 3, 200 * val)
                      ..rotateY((pi / 6) * val),
                    child: chilWidget));
              }),
          GestureDetector() **//Irrelevant code**
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

And it will look like this:

[image]

And here's how I use it for other `file.dart` files:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayOut( //I use here
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Favorites Page"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Text('Thanks you!'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Although it can still run normally without any warning being given, I am currently facing a few problems where `LayOut` is used. The first is when I use `DropDownFormField`, the selected value cannot be displayed to the screen even though it has been selected and added to the Firestore. Second, when I do Search, the value can't be displayed on the screen either.

I have tried pausing `LayOut` and everything is working properly.

Is this a conflict between the `Scaffolds`? How can I use that `LayOut` for other pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like the following code. Put your screen names into list. This example is the bottom navigation bar. But same logic goes for side navigation.

```
int _page = 0;
    final screens = [
        ScreenOne(),
        ScreenTwo(),
        ScreenThree(),
        ScreenFour(),
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
                
                bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
                  index: 0,
                  
                  items: [
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.home,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.calendarAlt,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.userAlt,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                  onTap: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      _page = index;
                    });
                  },
                  body: screens[_page]
                ),
    }
```